# Polygon fillColor issue

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Polyline feature for drawing on the map
I stored polylines into array in drawing   :

```
List<Polyline> polylines;
```

And After draw finished, i want to convert this polylines to polygons , but some times Polygons does not fill with color,

```
for(Polyline polyline : polylinesListContiner)
{
    List<LatLng> points = polyline.getPoints();
    PolygonOptions polygoneRctOptions = new PolygonOptions();

    polygoneRctOptions.addAll(points);
    polygoneRctOptions.fillColor(Color.RED);
    polygoneRctOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
    Polygon polygon = getGoogleMap().addPolygon(polygoneRctOptions);
    polygonPoints.add(polygon.getPoints());
    polygonList.add(polygon);
}
```

This problem will occur when my polyline is like this image :

[image]